# How to get a list of Facebook friends and their emails, birthdays and relationship status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a list of friends and with the following information {email, birthday, relationship status}

Right now I can only get the name and id with this snippet

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
     ...
});
```

Is there any way to get that information or is just limited to name and id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, using the current APIs

```
$facebook->api('me/friends?fields=name,birthday,relationship_status')
```

This will work with any field of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) you can retrieve

It's not possible to retrieve friends' email addresses at all, and other fields may require your user to grant you a specific [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) first, but the basic format of the API call is the same.

The example above needs friends_birthday and friends_relationship_status permissions

Comment: That did it! Thanks!  I couldn't find relationship_status on the Permissions page though but it still returned the info.  Did I just miss it?  EDIT: Sorry just saw it in the User object.  Thanks again for the quick help!

Comment: it doesn't seem to be in the documentation actually, but i think it's another way to refer to friends_relationships, which is - the graph api explorer tool has both - i'm not sure if there's a difference

Answer (score 0):

```
$friendsIds = array(1,2,3);
$requestInfo = array(
'method' => 'users_getInfo',
'friends' => $friendsIds,
'user_info' => array('last_name', 'first_name', 'uid', 'birthday')
)
$userDetails = $facebook->api->($requestInfo);
print_r($userDetails);
```

in js checkout
[how to use facebook API getting friend's list in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491457/how-to-use-facebook-api-getting-friends-list-in-javascript)