# /me not documented on facebook's graph api docs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494048/569976 gives an example of how to get info about the current user:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  //  Stuff here
});
```

The problem is...  I don't see `/me` discussed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0 .

Does facebook have any documentation on `/me`? Is it officially supported despite not being documented?

Comment: It may have been supported, but then deprecated in favour of a new API. Your best bet is to use the existing supported APIs, since using `/me` might not work in the future.

Comment: It is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user . /me is just short version of /{user-id}.

Comment: It's documented on the homepage of the Graph API documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0